# How to get the number of days by subtraction from the datetime field and then filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is model:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    start_date = DateTimeField()
    end_date = DateTimeField()
    sot = IntegerField(help_text='days')
```

I want to subtract the start time from the end time to get the number of days to compare with sot and filter out the data I want.
I can get what I want through the loop, but this is very inelegant, is there any way to do it through ORM?

```
[w for w in Work.objects.all() if (w.end_date - w.start_date).days < w.sot ]
```

Comment: [`F()` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [F expiression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

1. Use `F` to reference field `end_date` and `start_date`
2. Subtract `start_date` from `end_date`, which give a timestamp difference in microseconds.
3. Convert the timestamp difference in microseconds to days
4. Filter the day difference with `sot` field

```
Work.objects.filter(sot__gt=(F('end_date')-F('start_date'))/(3600*24*1000*1000))
```

Comment: Hello, my sot field is changed to hours, i try to do it like this `Q(sot__lt=(now().date() - F('start_time__date')) / (3600 * 1000 * 1000))` Although no error was reported, the result was wrong. Do you know why?

Comment: You can't use `now()` function with the F expression, I have checked the raw query with your `Q` expression, and found that the time diff is not correct.

Comment: the actual query being executed is like this `SELECT "app_work"."id", "app_work"."start_date", "app_work"."end_date", "app_work"."sot" FROM "app_work" WHERE "app_work"."sot" > (((2019-12-24 15:17:22.753758+00:00 - "app_work"."start_date") / 3600000000))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to use now () to filter when there is no end_date, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: sorry, not quite sure how to achieve this, maybe you can try using the database now function instead of python now function

Comment: It's OK.Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found a way  ```class SubDateByHour(Aggregate):
    function = 'DATE_SUB'
    template = '%(function)s(CURDATE(), INTERVAL %(expressions)s HOUR)'

    def __init__(self, expression, **extra):
        super(SubDateByHour, self).__init__(
            expression,
            output_field=DateTimeField(),
            **extra
        )```